# Error using Objective-C structure in Swift (Cannot find type 'XXX' in scope)

Tags: swift, objective-c, struct, bridging-header

In my sample project, I tried using the Objective-C classes and struct in the Swift file using the bridging headers. I get an error using the struct:

> Cannot find type 'XXX' in scope

However, classes are used without any error.

My Objective-C file looks like:

```objc
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

struct ObjCStruct {
    NSMenu* sMenu;
    int8_t menuID;
};

@interface ObjCClass : NSObject {
    NSMenu* cMenu;
}

@end
```

In my bridging header, I have used it as:

```objc
#import "ObjC.h"
```

Finally, I used struct and classes in Swift file as:

```swift
struct Model {
    var c : ObjCClass;
    var s : ObjCStruct;
}
```

If `NSMenu* sMenu;` has been commented out from ObjC.h, then it works fine.

How can I use the Objective-C struct in the Swift file?

I have imported the Objective-C headers in the bridging header and the bridging header has been referred correctly in the build settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using struct with objects is very tricky for memory management. Struct in objective-c is not the same as struct in Swift. You may reconsider declaring it a class. However, I think this is a workaround:

```
struct ObjCStruct {
    __unsafe_unretained  NSMenu* sMenu; //It's __strong by default
    int8_t menuID;
};
```

In Swift:

```swift
//Manage NSMenu manually by Unmanaged. Keep in mind to release this menu 
//object later or you will get a leak here.

let menu: Unmanaged<NSMenu> = Unmanaged.passRetained(NSMenu(title: "2"))
let model = Model(c: .init(), s: .init(sMenu: menu, menuID: 2))
```

```swift
//To get the NSMenu
let menuUI = menu.takeRetainedValue()
```

Comment: It works! Thanks for answer. How did you come to the answer? Can you tell me what I needs to study to understand more about this?

Comment: I faced this issue before, and I researched it. That's it, haha. Btw, if you're interested in ARC, you may want to take a look at this old [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). And I think briding always has issues, and you have to find a way to work around them.